# technical problem using intel parallel studio with cilk_spawn

Tags: spawn, cilk, intel-parallel-studio

I work with intel parallel studio 2011 and I included:

```
#include <cilk/cilk.h>
```

which seemed to be included just fine.

Then I tried using the command:

```
cilk_spawn (and also _Cilk_spawn)
```

and got the following error:

```
Error: identifier "_Cilk_spawn" is undefined.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like this problem doesn't interest the world too much :)

But for those of you interested, it turns out that the code compiles nicely and runs just fine - it is just some mysterious problem with the text view which makes look like it is a syntax error though it is not...

Comment: Is the library linked ? I have used the Cilk in linux, where i have the `cilkc` tool to make the executables, which accepts cilk's new keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Some mysterious problem with the text view which makes look like it is a syntax error" which you refer to in the comment probably means that Microsoft's Intellisense cannot recognize Cilk keywords, which are Intel's extension to C/C++.

I was unable to find any fix or workaround for that, so suggest you ask at [Intel's Cilk Plus forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-cilk-plus/); maybe Intel Parallel Studio can take care of it. Also see [a bug report to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646449/intel-cilk-c-technologies-keywords-not-accepted-by-intellisense).